# How to correctly render (deduce in pug / jade) the data in the project on node.js + express + postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pug, psql

I recently started learning node.js, I started to make an application on node.js + express + postgresql, as in the example presented here [Rest api node postgre (pg-promise)](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WnFh0K66_Rb) did not understand how to output to html for subsequent parsing in a table, for example the result of the function " getAllPuppies ", and how to render it in pug. Example [routes](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/blob/master/routes/index.js), [app.js](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/blob/master/app.js), [queries.js (server.js)](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/blob/master/queries.js), [public](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/tree/master/public) and the table itself is an example of [psql](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/blob/master/puppies.sql). I can not really figure out how to pass a value from the routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../queries');


// router.get('/', db.getAllAlarms);
router.get('/Unix/:unixtime', db.getSingleCDRUnix);
//router.put('/api/alarms/:id', db.updateAlarm);
//router.delete('/api/alarms/:id', db.removeAlarm);

router.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index',{?????});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Pug

```
view
    html
  head
    title= title
  body

 p
  h1= 'Oooomphf'
  a= {????}
  hr
```

Comment: Can you add a specific [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to do, or what you have tried to do?  Also a guide on building a REST API might not be the best place to start for rendering html from pug templates.

Comment: Thank you for the operative response, I can not really figure out how to pass a value from the routes/index.js var express = require('express');
           var router = express.Router();
           var db = require('../queries');
                                 router.get('/index', function (req, res) {
res.render('index',{obj:db.getAllAlarms});
    });
  module.exports = router;
)

Comment: Ok, you can edit the original question and paste that in and apply code formatting by clicking the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

The postgres library uses promises, so you will need to resolve the asynchronous query before returning the data with `res.render`, similar to how the [API responses work in the REST examples](https://github.com/mjhea0/node-postgres-promises/blob/master/queries.js#L12-L25).

```
router.get('/index', function (req, res, next) {
  db.getAllAlarms()
    .then(all_alarms => {
      res.render('index', { obj: all_alarms });
    })
    .catch(next)
});
```

The equivalent code using ES2017 [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) (Node 7.6+)

```
router.get('/index', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let all_alarms = await db.getAllAlarms()
    res.render('index', { obj: all_alarms });
  catch (err) {
    return next(err)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank's @Matt, but when I try to do according to your example, got : Unhandled rejection TypeError: next is not a function

Comment: That's odd, the `next` function is a standard express feature, in this case it's used with the error to trigger the error handler